# No Template for interactive request rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

Trying to add one route and respective controllers and views but getting error.[image]

Tried with adding erb file in views folder.

Comment: you haven't listed anything more than the error, making it difficult to point to the exact problem, but by convention in rails you will have a route which points to a controller, which points to a subdirectory in the view folder.  So in this case it would be something like route: `get "/main", to: "main#index", as: main - and a controller which contains at minimnum, 'class MainController < ApplicationController ; def index ; end  ; end' - view: app/views/main/index.html.erb - if any of those things are missing, I'd start there.

Comment: “I tried to add one routes and respective controllers and views” Great! But in order to help you we need to be able to see the structure of those and their location. Otherwise we can’t help

Answer (score 0):

Hard to diagnose with the little information you’ve provided, but given this statement:

> Tried with adding erb file in views folder

It sounds like you’ve place your `index.html.erb` which corresponds to your `MainController` directly in your views folder.

Rails expects this to be located within a folder that reflects the controllers name. Ie `views/main`

I recommend checking out the [official documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#overview-how-the-pieces-fit-together) to learn more about how everything flows.